# What is the airflow in sequential_executor logs

Tags: airflow

I am new to apache airflow and would like to ask simple question related to scheduler. When I am trying to run my DAG I am getting error as -
Persmission Error [13]: Permission Denied 'airflow'

When I check the above loggs, sequential_executor printed INFO message as 
sequential_executer.py 45  INFO Executing Command: ['airflow', 'run', 'test','report_list' .... ]

Could you please let me know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have added airflow library path and its resolved